# Fetch location or coordinates specfic posts using facebook search api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

Is there are way to fetch location/coordinate specific public posts using the facebook search api (`https://graph.facebook.com/search/?q=KEYWORD&type=post ...`)? I want this to be a general search query, without any user authorization.

I tried using `https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=...` , but this requires access_token and returns objects(not posts) posted only by friends of the user whose access token is used for querying.

I also tried `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=samsung&type=post&center=12.9833,77.5833&distance=1000&access_token=[I-USED-ANY-ACCESS-TOKEN]`, but I dont think this is giving me the location specific results as I am not receiving any loc info in the json response.

Are there any free data sources/APIs that can provide me `location/coordinate/ip` specific posts/data/tweets/feeds, etc from the web / social networking websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to walk the FB graph to get such places and their coordinates for types like `event`, `place`, `checkin`.  For example:

Search ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dconference%26type%3Devent)):

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dconference%26type%3Devent
```

Then pick one of the results and do ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=463944956965055)):

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=463944956965055
```

Then lookup the venue id's coordinates ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=199344279273)):

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=199344279273
```

Check the [FQL table definitions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) to verify that location coordinates are provided.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't really answer the question.

The answer is no, there isn't a way to search for general posts by location (excluding your friends). It's probably to protect user privacy.