# Fetch location or coordinates specfic posts using google plus public activities search api

Tags: google-plus

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550459/fetch-location-or-coordinates-specfic-posts-using-facebook-search-api) about searching location specific public posts on facebook, but got no replies.

My question remains same for google plus too. Is there any way to fetch location/coordinate specific public activities using the google plus search api (`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities` or any other api call)? I want this to be a general search query, without any user authorization.

If this is impossible, then are any free data sources/APIs that can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the REST API for Activities, you can retrieve posts--some of which will include location data in the geocode field.

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities

Also, if you retrieve an image from its url, you may be able to find location information from the exif metadata.  There are a number of free exif parsers, and many cameras today populate exif data into the image.